# Sqlite DB not returning data

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I tried to insert some data into my table, even it's inserted when I tried to select all data, db not returning any data.

here's my code:

**This is my DBHelper**

```
public boolean insertTransaksi (String timestamp, String jenis_tiket, String jumlah_orang, String total_biaya, Integer status) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("timestamp", timestamp);
    contentValues.put("jenis_tiket", jenis_tiket);
    contentValues.put("jumlah_orang", jumlah_orang);
    contentValues.put("total_biaya", total_biaya);
    contentValues.put("status", status);
    db.insert(TRANSAKSI_TABLE, null, contentValues);
    return true;
}

public ArrayList<String> getAllTransaksi() {
    ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor =  db.rawQuery( "select * from "+TRANSAKSI_TABLE, null );
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
        array_list.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("jumlah_orang")));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    return array_list;
}
```

And this is where I tried to insert and select data:

```
                if(db.insertTransaksi(timestamp, jenistTiket, jumlah, tHarga, 0)){
                    System.out.println("inserted");
                    ArrayList allTransaksi = db.getAllTransaksi();
                    Iterator iter = allTransaksi.iterator();
                    while (iter.hasNext()) {
                        System.out.println(iter.next());
                    }
                }else{
                    System.out.println("fail insert");
                }
```

the logcat returning "inserted" as i set if the command true. please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: which exception you are getting while inserting data ?

Comment: I miss one column name when create the table evidently, so when I try to select the column name (which is i don't create yet) it throws an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
 long insertOrThrow (String table, 
                String nullColumnHack, 
                ContentValues values)
```

instead of `insert()` and also check the return value which is the row ID of the newly inserted row.

Comment: oh thank for the answer! it turns out to throw an exception while insert data.